# How to programmatically do JSF internal page forward?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, forward

How to do JSF internal page forward programatically in managed bean, on some condition (like whenever an exception occurs)? I do not want to change the URL while forwarding to other page.

Right now I redirect to another page programmatically using this, but this changes the URL.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void forward(){
    String uri = "destination.xhtml";
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch(uri);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,.. this works! Is this standard way to do page forward programmatically or is it a workaround ?

Comment: @user01: this is the standard way at the moment :)

Comment: this is Servlet redirection, to use JSF navigation handler use: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "YOUR_NAVIGATION_CASE_DEFINED_IN_FACES_CONFIG");

Answer (score 1):

You can do using

```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setViewId("your target view id");
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
```

or you can use

```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Hope this helps.